# Would like to access remote linux machine console in a java web application running at different machine

Tags: java, python

I have a java web application both deployed and running at a linux machine, and there is one more machine where python service is running. here, the objective is to send some http requests/response from/to this python service. this functionality is working fine. but, there is one more requirement I want to access python machine (ubuntu) console  in java web application. Please suggest how to accomplish this task. What concept/feature helps to achieve this.

thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Why do you need that? Consider creating some HTTP API on that python service instead.

Comment: It sounds like a big security headache to allow a web application the ability to run arbitrary commands on the "python" machine. I agree with @torvin - just expose the limited set of things you need to do via HTTP.